# Polymorphism, calling the right function

Tags: c#, asp.net, polymorphism

I have a specific function in multi tier class system that is called and it picks the right function when it is called. How do I tell it to pick the function in a specific class?

Please let me know what other information is required from me to get the correct answer as I am not sure if this is enough or too vague. Let me know specifically what I need to provide as I am new to c# as well.

Comment: Sounds like multiple dispatch.

Comment: You have an inheritance heirachy like `class A{}` `class B:A{}` `C:B{}` and want to call instanceOfA.SomeMethod() and have the C.SomeMethod execute? If that's the case you'll want to mark the method as virtual. Honestly the question is difficult to understand.

Comment: Could you, perhaps, add some details to your question.  It would help to have the code for `a specific function` and then we could probably help you refactor so you get the results you want.

Comment: Yes, I knew it was a hard question to understand. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created the most basic example for polymorphism which I can think of. Try to understand the example and the comments, I will update the post if you have more specific questions.

The first code example contains two classes, the second calls the methods of objects of these classes to demonstrate polymorphism.

```
public class BaseClass
{
    // This method can be "replaced" by classes which inherit this class
    public virtual void OverrideableMethod()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("BaseClass.OverrideableMethod()");
    }

    // This method is called when the type is of your variable is "BaseClass"
    public void Method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("BaseClass.Method()");
    }
}

public class SpecializedClass : BaseClass
{

    // your specialized code
    // the original method from BaseClasse is not accessible anymore
    public override void OverrideableMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SpecializedClass.OverrideableMethod()");

        // call the base method if you need to
        // base.OverrideableMethod();
    }

    // this method hides the Base Classes code, but it still is accessible
    // - without the "new" keyword the compiler generates a warning
    // - try to avoid method hiding
    // - it is called when the type is of your variable is "SpecializedClass"
    public new void Method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SpecializedClass.Method()");
    }
}
```

test the classes using something like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("testing base class");

BaseClass baseClass = new BaseClass();
baseClass.Method();
baseClass.OverrideableMethod();


Console.WriteLine("\n\ntesting specialized class");

SpecializedClass specializedClass = new SpecializedClass();
specializedClass.Method();
specializedClass.OverrideableMethod();


Console.WriteLine("\n\nuse specialized class as base class");

BaseClass containsSpecializedClass = specializedClass;
containsSpecializedClass.Method();
containsSpecializedClass.OverrideableMethod();
```